# Following each new cube being created during geometry delete

Tags: geometry-nodes

As shown in the image I have a sphere sitting in a static position above cubes that get generated one at a time.  I would like the sphere object to move one at at time directly above the center of each newly created cube. If it's not too complicated I'd like it to gracefully glide across as each cube is created with a delay.

Rather than creating a manually keyed animation, I'd like to use Geometry Nodes.

I tried a few things including trying a shared attribute value from GM nodes to a driver of the separate sphere but I didn't know if I could do that like sharing a color with shading nodes. I don't think I can force a move of a separate object from GN.

**3 Roadblocks seem to be holding me back:**

**1 & 2:** Passing and Receiving any value / vertex from GN to other objects (so I can affect them) with maybe a driver

**3:** Getting center position of cube after delete geometry
(This sounded like it might have solved it but it doesn't seem to work in my tests
https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/tb9cbs/geometry_nodes_how_can_i_access_the_position_of_a/ )

[image: Basic Geometry Node Setup]

I'd like the render to look something like this:
[image: Sample Animation]

[image]

Comment: I don't think I understand what your aim is from your description, can you show a visual example? You can use blend-exchange.com to upload files (it'll give you an html code, which you can edit into your post).

Comment: @Kuboå thanks for the tip and updated the question.  The complexity is getting the location of each new cube and somehow passing it to the floating sphere so it moves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not sure, but hopefully you mean it like that:

[image]

[image]

Comment: great and I just hid the view and render of the sphere to get your solution.